# Vaadin Combobox - no error upon invalid custom input

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am using Vaadin 14.1.21 and want a Dropdown box (Combobox) to display Integer-values, and also allow custom input.

I have Integer in the dataclass for the field as a type, but the UI fieldtype is String since I also need to enable custom input, . I use withConverter in combination with a custom converter as I don't want to display the thousand-separator (dot in my case) in the UI. It works as expected for all supplied drop down items - and when I select the supplied 'invalid' item of the dropdown menu ("Error Message Item"), I get my custom error displayed beneath the combobox.

The problem appears when I input an invalid custom value, e.g. "329hhh2" - **I get no error upon invalid custom-input from my custom converter**!

I don't get any error at all and when I want to "save" my object, the (invalid) combobox value just disappears into nirvana and I get Null as the field-value.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code example (i tried to keep it as short as possible without leaving anything out):

```
public class RisikoForm extends Div {

    private ComboBox<String> number_string_combobox;

    public void instantiate_string_combobox() {
        number_string_combobox = new ComboBox<>();
        number_string_combobox.setItems("6583212", "114514", "879278", "Error Message Item");
        number_string_combobox.setLabel("Number");
        number_string_combobox.addCustomValueSetListener(event -> event.getDetail());
    }


    private static class Id_StringToInteger_Converter extends StringToIntegerConverter {

        public Id_StringToInteger_Converter() {
            super("Custom Error: Input cannot be converted to integer");
        }

        @Override
        protected NumberFormat getFormat(Locale locale) {
            final NumberFormat format = super.getFormat(locale);
            format.setGroupingUsed(false);
            return format;
        }
    }

    public Form(ViewLogic sampleCrudLogic) {
        this.instantiate_string_combobox();
        content.add(number_string_combobox);

        binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Data.class);
        binder.forField(number_string_combobox)
              .withNullRepresentation("")
              .withConverter(new Id_StringToInteger_Converter())
              .bind(Data::getIntegerNumber, Data::setIntegerNumber);
    }
}


public class Data implements Serializable {

   private Integer integerNumber;

    public Integer getIntegerNumber() {
        return integerNumber;
    }

    public void setIntegerNumber(Integer integerNumber) {
        this.integerNumber = integerNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would say it has to do with the addCustomValueSetListener. Read the ApiDoc of Combobox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom value set listener is a no-op right now.  You have to react on the event.  E.g.:

```
addCustomValueSetListener(event -> number_string_combobox.setValue(event.getDetail()))
```

See the [example under "Allow custom values" or "Storing custom values"](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples)

Comment: this is great!! Thank you so much!   One more question, do you know how I can change the validation "eager" for custom values in the combobox? I only found this functionality for textfields so far

Comment: Something along the lines of "textfield.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);"  for combobox custom inputs

Comment: @Cribber AFAIK not.  I'd check the github issues for that and then the vaadin forum.